# How can I launch 2 applications from current simultaneously (one in background)?

Tags: android, android-intent, launch

I want to launch 2 Android applications from the current application. One of them should be launched in background and the other one in foreground with which user will interact with now. When I try the existing solutions for launching multiple intents (like `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)`and`try....finally)`, they don't work, probably because when 1 application is launched device switches to that instantly; and these solutions are for intents launching multiple activities in the same applications. Please suggest a solution other than launching one as a service.

**UPDATE - Answer:**

Based on David Wasser's answer, this works:

```
    final Intent intent1=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("example.app1.package");
    final Intent intent2=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("example.app3.package");
    Handler mHandler=new Handler();
    Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                      startActivity(intent1);
             }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,1000);
    startActivity(intent2);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "launched in the background"?

Comment: Such that if I launch from app A -> apps B and C; C should be the app user now interacts with. If C is closed, he interacts with A, while B is also running.

Comment: Please put your answer in an answer or add a comment to David's answer adding what was missing to your success. The answer however should not remain in your question :)

Comment: I had put it as an answer, David Wasser suggested that I put it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Here are 2:

1) Launch App B. Start a background thread or post a `Runnable` to a `Handler` that will launch App C after a few seconds. You need to give Android enough time to actually launch App B and have it displayed on screen. If you then launch App C at a later time, it will appear on top of App B.

2) Launch App B and have App B launch App C itself. You could pass an "extra" in the `Intent` you use to launch App B and App B can use the presence of this "extra" to know that it should launch App C.

Answer (score 0):

David Wasser's answer is right, this code works:

```
final Intent intent1=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("example.app1.package");
    final Intent intent2=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("example.app3.package");
    Handler mHandler=new Handler();
    Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                      startActivity(intent1);
             }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,1000);
    startActivity(intent2);
```

Comment: You shouldn't add this as an answer. It would be better if you add this in your original question. Just edit your original question and add this code with an explanation at the bottom of your question. It will get more attention there than here. You can then delete this answer.